# subString of a String with a specific frequency

Tags: java, string

Considering the following string, I would like to get a substring in that way:

```
String str="abcdefghij"
```

Substring returned:

```
 acegi
```

that is to say every two chars of the first string str.
Then with the same reasoning, getting a substring of every three chars of the first string str.

And the same question with a frequency of f

This is my current method but actually there is an error:

```
 private static String subString(String str,int freq){
        String subStr=null;

        for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); freq++){
          subStr= subStr + str[i];
        }
     return subStr;
 }
```

Also maybe there is some already existing method for these tasks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a built-in method to do it. You could use a StringBuilder to avoid creating many temporary strings, and initialise it with the right capacity:

```
private static String subString(String str, int freq) {
    //make it the right capacity to avoid reallocations
    StringBuilder subStr = new StringBuilder(str.length() / freq + 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i += freq) {
        subStr.append(str.charAt(i));
    }
    return subStr.toString();
}
```

Comment: Could the downvoter leave a comment?

Comment: Endless loop for strings with length > 0 ;)

Comment: Outch... Terrible copy paste indeed... Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: +1, for using the (in this case) _better_ constructor of the StringBuilder. Although it wouldn't make a difference for the provided example.

Comment: +1 for giving the string builder an initial capacity

Answer (score 1):

You need every `freq`-th character in the string. Try this

```
    String subStr="";

    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i+=freq){
      subStr= subStr + str.charAt(i);
    }
```

EDIT: a better idea is to use a StringBuilder, see the answer of @asgoth

Answer (score 1):

**Please for iterating, use a StringBuilder!** I have seen such constructs like you use, blow up an application server.

```
private static String subString(String str,int freq){
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();

    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i+=freq){
      out.append(str.charAt(i));
    }
    return out.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static subString(String str, int freq){
String subStr;
for(int i=0;i<str.length();i+=freq){
  subStr=subStr+str.charAt(i);
}
return subStr;
}
```

Here's the method for your request. There's no built in ones.